# Interpreting derivative questions in context

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

[image]

I have these two questions and I am able to approximate $S''(10)$ like this:

$\frac{S'(12)-S'(8)}{12-8}=-0.05$

I am just unsure how to interpret the meaning of $S''(x)$ in context. I know that the second derivative tells you whether your graph is concave up or concave down, which tells you whether or not the the first derivative (slope of the tangent line) is increasing or decreasing.

So would an adequate explanation be: $S''(x)$ shows the change in rate of snow deposition with respect to time?

For the second problem, I have the same question. I have $D'(t) = \frac{92}{40}e^{-t/40}$

and $D'(10)\approx 1.79$ cm/hr

Is the correct interpretation: $D'(10)$ is the rate that the snow is depositing in centimeters per hour at $t=10$ hours.

Answer (score 1):

In this case S"(x) represents the rate of the rate of snow piling up. For example, when we say a car is accelerating, it means that the rate at which its going forward is positive.

Note that the units for rate of rate would be units/time^2, since the units would be units/time/time.

For your second question, you are correct when you claimed that D'(10) represents the rate at which the snow is depositing in centimeters per hour.